# is it possible to use "fopen" or "open" to open the current program (argv[0])

Tags: c, fopen

I'm basically trying to create a `FILE` pointer to the current file (`argv[0]`) using `fopen()`
but it returns a SegFault, I tried to print the error and got a : Text file busy. This is what I got.
Obviously the error is on line 14, `if (localFile == NULL)`

```c
void copy(char *localFileName, char *targetFileName) {
    int ch;
    FILE *localFile = fopen(localFileName, "r+b");
    FILE *targetFile = fopen(targetFileName, "r+b");
    FILE *tempFile = fopen("tempFile.bin", "wb+");
    if (tempFile == NULL) {
        perror("tempFile");
    }

    if (targetFile == NULL) {
        perror("targetFile");
    }

    if (localFile == NULL) {
        perror("localFile");
    }
    while((ch = fgetc(localFile)) != EOF) { 
        fputc(ch, tempFile);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(targetFile)) != EOF) {
        fputc(ch, tempFile);
    }
    fclose(localFile);
    fclose(targetFile);
}
```

Comment: Try opening argv[0] with mode "rb", not "r+b". If that works, I will explain.

Comment: Some systems might let you open the file for appending or writing, but your system appears to prevent it. If you tried `"rb"` to open it read-only, instead of `"r+b"` to open it for appending, the system might let you. If you are hoping to open the file so that you can change the executing program while it is running, that is probably not going to happen, and, if it did, it would likely not work the way you want it to.

Comment: firstly, it didn't work, and no, I'm not trying to edit the file, I just wanna copy it's content (in binary) and paste them to a new file

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: oh, nvm it worked, and I'm using Linux Debian 10 :) thanks!!!!

Comment: @EricPostpischil It looks like POSIX.1 forbids writing and executing a "pure procedure file" at the same time. Maybe the definition of "pure procedure file" is flexible, though.

Comment: Keep in mind that `argv[0]` is not guaranteed to be the name of your program's executable.  If this is for testing or debugging, fine, but don't rely on this approach for a real program.

Comment: What's the alternative then??

Comment: On Linux, `readlink("/proc/self/exe")` is likely the name of the program's own executable file. If you really want to open it, probably best to just `fopen("/proc/self/exe", flags)`. Not entirely sure what gotchas there might be with that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible but you should be aware of some things that may make it difficult :-)

- There's no guarantee that `argv[0]` will be set to the *actual* file name of the program running. The standard only states that, in the event the information is available at all, it "represents the program name". That "represents" allows for "prog", "/full/path/to/prog", "./relative/path/to/prog", or even "prog program located in application directory". What is provided is very *much* implementation dependent (the `procfs` file system, if available, may provide better information, such as from `/proc/self/exe`).
- There's no guarantee you'll be able to open it anyway, due to various limitations. For example, it's unlikely in modern environments that you'll be able to open it in one of the modes that include update access as it may be used as the backing store for paging parts of the executable in and out of main memory.
- Even if that were *not* the case, you can configure access to be able to execute programs but not read them (`--x` mode). In that case, you couldn't open the file for reading even if it were not locked by the paging system.